# Why don't I have all permissions when I am logged on as root?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform

This is a GCP MySQL Cloud instance, MySQL 2nd Gen 5.7. Google installed and configured it.

I am logged in as root:
[image]

When I run a script to create schemas, tables, and views, I get this error:

```
Error Code: 1227. Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

Here are the permissions assigned to root:
[image]

Here is the SQL that fails, in the form of a stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `CreateFullCoverageTestCase`()
BEGIN
    -- Create all the elements of the Full Coverage Test Case

    -- *********************
    -- Schema Store
    -- *********************
    Begin
        DROP Schema if exists `store`;
    END;
    BEGIN
        CREATE SCHEMA `store` ;

        CREATE TABLE `store`.`city` (
          `CityID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `City` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`CityID`),
          UNIQUE KEY `City_UNIQUE` (`City`));
        INSERT INTO store.city (City) VALUES('Cincinnati');
        INSERT INTO store.city (City) VALUES('Columbus');
        INSERT INTO store.city (City) VALUES('Kokomo');
        INSERT INTO store.city (City) VALUES('Hillsdale');
        INSERT INTO store.city (City) VALUES('Lexington');
        INSERT INTO store.city (City) VALUES('Oxford');

        CREATE TABLE `store`.`state` (
          `StateID` int(11)  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `State` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
          `StateAbbreviation` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`StateID`),
          UNIQUE KEY `StateAbbreviation_UNIQUE` (`StateAbbreviation`),
          UNIQUE KEY `State_UNIQUE` (`State`),
          UNIQUE KEY `StateID_UNIQUE` (`StateID`));
        INSERT INTO store.state (State, StateAbbreviation) VALUES('Indiana', 'IN');
        INSERT INTO store.state (State, StateAbbreviation) VALUES('Kentucky', 'KY');
        INSERT INTO store.state (State, StateAbbreviation) VALUES('Michigan', 'MI');
        INSERT INTO store.state (State, StateAbbreviation) VALUES('Ohio', 'OH');

        CREATE TABLE `store`.`store` (
          `StoreID` int(11)  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `StoreNumber` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
          `AddressLine1` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
          `AddressLine2` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
          `CityID` int(11) NOT NULL,
          `StateID` int(11) NOT NULL,
          `ZipCode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`StoreID`),
          UNIQUE KEY `StoreNumber_UNIQUE` (`StoreNumber`));
        INSERT INTO store.store (StoreNumber, AddressLine1, CityID, StateID, ZipCode) VALUES('S000000001', '111 Main', 1, 4, '45255-1321');
        INSERT INTO store.store (StoreNumber, AddressLine1, CityID, StateID, ZipCode) VALUES('S000000002', '817 Nordyke', 1, 4, '45103-0000');
        INSERT INTO store.store (StoreNumber, AddressLine1, CityID, StateID, ZipCode) VALUES('S000000003', '123 Green', 6, 4, '45056-0000');

    End;
    -- *********************
    -- Schema HR (Human Resources)
    -- *********************
    BEGIN
        DROP Schema if exists `hr`;
    END;
    BEGIN
        CREATE SCHEMA `hr` ;
        CREATE TABLE `hr`.`employee` (
          `EmployeeID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `LastName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
          `FirstName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
          `EmployeeNumber` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
          `AddressLine1` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
          `AddressLine2` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
          `City` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
          `State` VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
          `ZipCode` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`EmployeeID`),
          UNIQUE INDEX `EmployeeNumber_UNIQUE` (`EmployeeNumber` ASC));
        INSERT INTO hr.employee (lastName, firstName, EmployeeNumber, AddressLine1, City, State, ZipCode) VALUES('Cheaney', 'Calbert', 'E000000001', '17th Street', 'Bloomington', 'IN', '47405');
        INSERT INTO hr.employee (lastName, firstName, EmployeeNumber, AddressLine1, City, State, ZipCode) VALUES('Reynolds', 'Chris', 'E000000002', 'Fee Street', 'Bloomington', 'IN', '47405');

    END;
    -- *********************
    -- Products for sale
    -- *********************
    BEGIN
        DROP Schema if exists `product`;
    END;
    BEGIN
        CREATE SCHEMA `product` ;
        CREATE TABLE `product`.`manufacturer` (
          `ManufacturerID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `Manufacturer` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
          `Comment` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
          `AddressLine01` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
          `AddressLine02` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
          `City` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
          `State` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
          `ZipCode` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
          `Phone` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
          `Manufacturercol` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`ManufacturerID`),
          UNIQUE KEY `Manufacturer_UNIQUE` (`Manufacturer`));
        INSERT INTO product.manufacturer (Manufacturer) VALUES('Smuckers');
        INSERT INTO product.manufacturer (Manufacturer) VALUES('Dannon');
        INSERT INTO product.manufacturer (Manufacturer) VALUES('Kellogs');
        INSERT INTO product.manufacturer (Manufacturer) VALUES('Pepsi');

        CREATE TABLE `product`.`unit` (
          `UnitID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `Unit` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`UnitID`),
          UNIQUE INDEX `Unit_UNIQUE` (`Unit` ASC));
        INSERT INTO product.unit(Unit) VALUES('Box');
        INSERT INTO product.unit(Unit) VALUES('Bag');
        INSERT INTO product.unit(Unit) VALUES('Carton');
        INSERT INTO product.unit(Unit) VALUES('Jar');
        INSERT INTO product.unit(Unit) VALUES('Tube');
        INSERT INTO product.unit(Unit) VALUES('Case');
        INSERT INTO product.unit(Unit) VALUES('Cup');

        CREATE TABLE `product`.`product` (
          `ProductID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `SKU` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
          `Description` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
          `ManufacturerID` int(11) NOT NULL,
          `UnitCost` decimal(10,3) DEFAULT '0.000',
          `UnitPrice` decimal(10,3) DEFAULT '0.000',
          `UnitID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`ProductID`),
          UNIQUE KEY `SKU_UNIQUE` (`SKU`),
          UNIQUE KEY `Description_UNIQUE` (`Description`),
          KEY `ManufacturerID_idx` (`ManufacturerID`),
          KEY `UnitID_idx` (`UnitID`),
          CONSTRAINT `ManufacturerID` FOREIGN KEY (`ManufacturerID`) REFERENCES `manufacturer` (`ManufacturerID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `UnitID` FOREIGN KEY (`UnitID`) REFERENCES `unit` (`UnitID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        );

        INSERT INTO product.product (SKU, Description, ManufacturerID, UnitCost, UnitPrice, UnitID) VALUES('P000000001', 'Blueberry Jam',                   1,  .50, 1.00, 4);
        INSERT INTO product.product (SKU, Description, ManufacturerID, UnitCost, UnitPrice, UnitID) VALUES('P000000002', 'Coffee Yogurt',                   2, 1.00, 2.00, 7);
        INSERT INTO product.product (SKU, Description, ManufacturerID, UnitCost, UnitPrice, UnitID) VALUES('P000000003', '12 Individual Boxes Corn Flakes', 3, 1.00, 5.00, 6);
        INSERT INTO product.product (SKU, Description, ManufacturerID, UnitCost, UnitPrice, UnitID) VALUES('P000000004', 'Box Corn Flakes',                 3, 1.00, 5.00, 1);

    END;
    -- *********************
    -- Loyalty (Customers)
    -- *********************
    BEGIN
        DROP schema if exists `loyalty`;
    END;
    BEGIN
        CREATE SCHEMA `loyalty`;
        CREATE TABLE `loyalty`.`loyalty` (
          `LoyaltyID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `LoyaltyNumber` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
          `LastName` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
          `FirstName` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
          `AddressLine1` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
          `AddressLine2` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
          `City` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
          `State` VARCHAR(2) NULL,
          `ZipCode` INT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`LoyaltyID`),
          UNIQUE INDEX `LoyaltyNumber_UNIQUE` (`LoyaltyNumber` ASC));        
        INSERT INTO loyalty.loyalty (LoyaltyID, LoyaltyNumber, LastName)            VALUES(1, 'L000000001', 'Smith');
        INSERT INTO loyalty.loyalty (LoyaltyID, LoyaltyNumber)                      VALUES(2, 'L000000002');
        INSERT INTO loyalty.loyalty (LoyaltyID, LoyaltyNumber)                      VALUES(3, 'L000000003');
        INSERT INTO loyalty.loyalty (LoyaltyID, LoyaltyNumber, LastName, FirstName) VALUES(4, 'L000000004', 'Knight', 'Robert');

    END;
    -- *********************
    -- Reconciled Schema 
    -- *********************
    BEGIN
        DROP Schema if exists `reconciled`;
    END;
    BEGIN
        CREATE SCHEMA `reconciled` ;
        CREATE TABLE `reconciled`.`sale` (
          `saleID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `EmployeeFirstName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
          `EmployeeLastName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
          `ProductDescription` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
          `Unit` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
          `SKU` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
          `Qty` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
          `UnitCost` decimal(10,3) DEFAULT NULL,
          `UnitPrice` decimal(10,3) DEFAULT NULL,
          `Manufacturer` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
          `EmployeeNumber` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The employee who handled the transaction',
          `LoyaltyNumber` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
          `StoreNumber` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
          `DateOfTransaction` date DEFAULT NULL,
          `TimeOfTransaction` time DEFAULT NULL,
          `DateOfTransactionString` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
          `TimeOfTransactionString` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
          `WeekdayOfTransaction` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
          `MonthOfTransaction` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
          `YearOfTransaction` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
          `WeekdayNameOfTransaction` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
          `MonthNameOfTransaction` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
          `TotalPrice` decimal(10,3) DEFAULT NULL,
          `ZipCode` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`saleID`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

        CREATE TABLE `reconciled`.`weather` (
          `WeatherID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `DateStamp` date DEFAULT NULL,
          `ZipCode` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
          `Temperature` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
          `MonthName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
          `YearNumber` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
          `DayName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
          `MonthNumber` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
          `DayNumber` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`WeatherID`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    END;
     -- *********************
    -- Aggregated schema for the data warehouse
    -- *********************
    BEGIN
        DROP Schema if exists dw;
        CREATE SCHEMA `dw` ;
        CREATE TABLE `dw`.`salesqtybyproductandstore` (
          `SalesByProductAndStoreID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `SKU` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
          `StoreNumber` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
          `ProductDescription` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
          `Monday` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
          `Tuesday` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
          `Wednesday` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
          `Thursday` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
          `Friday` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
          `Saturday` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
          `Sunday` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
          PRIMARY KEY (`SalesByProductAndStoreID`),
          UNIQUE KEY `SKU_UNIQUE` (`SKU`,`StoreNumber`)
        );
    END; 
    BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE `dw`.`monthlysalesqtybyproductandstore` (
          `monthlysalesqtybyproductandstoreID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `SKU` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
          `StoreNumber` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
          `ProductDescription` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
          `January` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
          `February` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
          `March` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
          `April` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
          `May` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
          `June` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
          `July` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
          `August` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
          `September` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
          `October` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
          `November` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
          `December` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
          PRIMARY KEY (`monthlysalesqtybyproductandstoreID`),
          UNIQUE KEY `SKU_UNIQUE` (`SKU`,`StoreNumber`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

        CREATE TABLE `dw`.`weeklysalesqtybyproductandstore` (
          `WeeklysalesqtybyproductandstoreID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `SKU` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
          `StoreNumber` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
          `ProductDescription` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
          `Monday` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
          `Tuesday` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
          `Wednesday` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
          `Thursday` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
          `Friday` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
          `Saturday` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
          `Sunday` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
          PRIMARY KEY (`WeeklysalesqtybyproductandstoreID`),
          UNIQUE KEY `SKU_UNIQUE` (`SKU`,`StoreNumber`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

        CREATE TABLE `dw`.`storesalesbytemperature` (
          `StoreSalesByTemperatureID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `StoreNumber` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
          `Under0` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
          `0To20` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
          `21To30` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
          `31To40` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
          `41To50` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
          `51To60` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
          `61To70` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
          `71To80` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
          `81To90` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
          `Over90` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
          `StoreSalesByTemperaturecol` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`StoreSalesByTemperatureID`),
          INDEX `Unique` (`StoreNumber` ASC));
    END;
    BEGIN
        DROP Schema if exists icecream;
        CREATE SCHEMA `icecream`;

        CREATE TABLE `icecream`.`flavor` (
          `FlavorID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `Flavor` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`FlavorID`),
          UNIQUE INDEX `Flavor_UNIQUE` (`Flavor` ASC));

        CREATE TABLE `icecream`.`container` (
          `ContainerID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `Container` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`ContainerID`),
          UNIQUE INDEX `Container_UNIQUE` (`Container` ASC));   

        CREATE TABLE `icecream`.`icecream` (
          `IceCreamID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `FlavorID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
          `ContainerID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
          `SKU` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`IceCreamID`),
          UNIQUE KEY `Unique` (`ContainerID`,`FlavorID`),
          UNIQUE KEY `SKU_UNIQUE` (`SKU`),
          CONSTRAINT `Container` FOREIGN KEY (`ContainerID`) REFERENCES `icecream`.`container` (`ContainerID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `Flavor` FOREIGN KEY (`FlavorID`) REFERENCES `icecream`.`flavor` (`FlavorID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

        INSERT INTO icecream.flavor (flavor)            VALUES('Chocolate');
        INSERT INTO icecream.flavor (flavor)            VALUES('Vanilla');
        INSERT INTO icecream.flavor (flavor)            VALUES('Strawberry');
        INSERT INTO icecream.flavor (flavor)            VALUES('Raspberry Chocolate Chip');
        INSERT INTO icecream.flavor (flavor)            VALUES('Blueberry');

        INSERT INTO icecream.container (Container)      VALUES('cup');
        INSERT INTO icecream.container (Container)      VALUES('pint');
        INSERT INTO icecream.container (Container)      VALUES('quart');
        INSERT INTO icecream.container (Container)      VALUES('half gallon');
        INSERT INTO icecream.container (Container)      VALUES('gallon');

        INSERT INTO icecream.icecream (flavorID, containerID, SKU)      VALUES(1, 2, 'I000000001');
        INSERT INTO icecream.icecream (flavorID, containerID, SKU)      VALUES(2, 2, 'I000000002');
        INSERT INTO icecream.icecream (flavorID, containerID, SKU)      VALUES(3, 2, 'I000000003');   
        INSERT INTO icecream.icecream (flavorID, containerID, SKU)      VALUES(1, 3, 'I000000004');
        INSERT INTO icecream.icecream (flavorID, containerID, SKU)      VALUES(2, 3, 'I000000005');
        INSERT INTO icecream.icecream (flavorID, containerID, SKU)      VALUES(3, 3, 'I000000006');

        INSERT INTO icecream.icecream (flavorID, containerID)      VALUES(4, 1);

    END;
        -- *********************
    -- Schema Sales
    -- *********************
    BEGIN
        DROP Schema if exists `weather`;
    END;
    BEGIN
        CREATE SCHEMA `weather` ;
        CREATE TABLE `weather`.`weather` (
          `weatherText` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

        INSERT INTO weather.weather (weatherText)       VALUES('2018/01/01 00:00:00.0000,45255,10');
        INSERT INTO weather.weather (weatherText)       VALUES('2018/01/02 00:00:00.0000,45255,12');
        INSERT INTO weather.weather (weatherText)       VALUES('2018/01/03 00:00:00.0000,45255,14');
        INSERT INTO weather.weather (weatherText)       VALUES('2018/01/04 00:00:00.0000,45255,16');
        INSERT INTO weather.weather (weatherText)       VALUES('2018/01/01 00:00:00.0000,45103,15');
        INSERT INTO weather.weather (weatherText)       VALUES('2018/01/02 00:00:00.0000,45103,17');
        INSERT INTO weather.weather (weatherText)       VALUES('2018/01/03 00:00:00.0000,45103,19');
        INSERT INTO weather.weather (weatherText)       VALUES('2018/01/04 00:00:00.0000,45103,21');

    END;    

    -- *********************
    -- Schema Sales
    -- *********************
    BEGIN
        DROP Schema if exists `sales`;
    END;
    BEGIN
        CREATE SCHEMA `sales` ;
        CREATE TABLE `sales`.`transaction` (
          `TransactionID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `DateTimeOfTransaction` datetime NOT NULL,
          `LoyaltyNumber` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
          `StoreNumber` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
          `EmployeeNumber` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`TransactionID`),
          UNIQUE KEY `NaturalKey` (`DateTimeOfTransaction`,`LoyaltyNumber`,`StoreNumber`,`EmployeeNumber`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
    END;
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO `sales`.`transaction` (TransactionID, DateTimeOfTransaction, LoyaltyNumber, StoreNumber, EmployeeNumber) VALUES(1, '2018-01-01 15:00:00', 'L000000001', 'S000000001', 'E000000001');
        INSERT INTO `sales`.`transaction` (TransactionID, DateTimeOfTransaction, LoyaltyNumber, StoreNumber, EmployeeNumber) VALUES(2, '2018-02-02 15:00:00', 'L000000002', 'S000000002', 'E000000002');
        INSERT INTO `sales`.`transaction` (TransactionID, DateTimeOfTransaction, LoyaltyNumber, StoreNumber, EmployeeNumber) VALUES(3, '2018-02-07 16:00:00', 'L000000002', 'S000000002', 'E000000002');
        INSERT INTO `sales`.`transaction` (TransactionID, DateTimeOfTransaction, LoyaltyNumber, StoreNumber, EmployeeNumber) VALUES(4, '2018-02-09 16:16:00', 'L000000002', 'S000000002', 'E000000002');
    END;
    BEGIN
          -- YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
        CREATE TABLE `sales`.`transactiondetail` (
          `TransactionDetailID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `TransactionID` int(11) NOT NULL,
          `SKU` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
          `Qty` int(11) NOT NULL,
          `TotalPrice` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,
          `Comment` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`TransactionDetailID`),
          UNIQUE KEY `NaturalKey` (`TransactionID`,`SKU`),
          KEY `TransactionID_idx` (`TransactionID`),
          CONSTRAINT `TransactionID` FOREIGN KEY (`TransactionID`) REFERENCES `sales`.`transaction` (`TransactionID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
    END;
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO sales.transactiondetail (TransactionID, SKU, Qty, TotalPrice) VALUES(1, 'P000000001', 10, 100);
        INSERT INTO sales.transactiondetail (TransactionID, SKU, Qty, TotalPrice) VALUES(1, 'P000000002',  5,  25);

        INSERT INTO sales.transactiondetail (TransactionID, SKU, Qty, TotalPrice) VALUES(2, 'P000000001',  1, 100);
        INSERT INTO sales.transactiondetail (TransactionID, SKU, Qty, TotalPrice) VALUES(2, 'P000000002',  2,  25);
        INSERT INTO sales.transactiondetail (TransactionID, SKU, Qty, TotalPrice) VALUES(3, 'P000000002', 40,  40);

        INSERT INTO sales.transactiondetail (TransactionID, SKU, Qty, TotalPrice) VALUES(4, 'P000000002', 44,  44);

    END;

    BEGIN
        CREATE 
            ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
            DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
            SQL SECURITY DEFINER
        VIEW `reconciled`.`mapping` AS
            SELECT 
                `hr`.`employee`.`FirstName` AS `EmployeeFirstName`,
                `hr`.`employee`.`LastName` AS `EmployeeLastName`,
                `product`.`product`.`Description` AS `ProductDescription`,
                `product`.`unit`.`Unit` AS `Unit`,
                `product`.`product`.`SKU` AS `SKU`,
                `sales`.`transactiondetail`.`Qty` AS `Qty`,
                `product`.`product`.`UnitCost` AS `UnitCost`,
                `product`.`product`.`UnitPrice` AS `UnitPrice`,
                `product`.`manufacturer`.`Manufacturer` AS `Manufacturer`,
                `sales`.`transaction`.`EmployeeNumber` AS `EmployeeNumber`,
                `sales`.`transaction`.`LoyaltyNumber` AS `LoyaltyNumber`,
                `sales`.`transaction`.`StoreNumber` AS `StoreNumber`,
                `store`.`store`.`zipCode` as `ZipCode`,
                CAST(`sales`.`transaction`.`DateTimeOfTransaction`
                    AS DATE) AS `DateOfTransaction`,
                CAST(`sales`.`transaction`.`DateTimeOfTransaction`
                    AS TIME) AS `TimeOfTransaction`,
                CAST(CAST(`sales`.`transaction`.`DateTimeOfTransaction`
                        AS DATE)
                    AS CHAR CHARSET UTF8) AS `DateOfTransactionString`,
                CAST(CAST(`sales`.`transaction`.`DateTimeOfTransaction`
                        AS TIME)
                    AS CHAR CHARSET UTF8) AS `TimeOfTransactionString`,
                WEEKDAY(`sales`.`transaction`.`DateTimeOfTransaction`) AS `WeekdayOfTransaction`,
                MONTH(`sales`.`transaction`.`DateTimeOfTransaction`) AS `MonthOfTransaction`,
                YEAR(`sales`.`transaction`.`DateTimeOfTransaction`) AS `YearOfTransaction`,
                DAYNAME(`sales`.`transaction`.`DateTimeOfTransaction`) AS `WeekdayNameOfTransaction`,
                MONTHNAME(`sales`.`transaction`.`DateTimeOfTransaction`) AS `MonthNameOfTransaction`,
                `sales`.`transactiondetail`.`TotalPrice` AS `TotalPrice`
            FROM
                ((((((`sales`.`transaction`
                JOIN `sales`.`transactiondetail` ON ((`sales`.`transaction`.`TransactionID` = `sales`.`transactiondetail`.`TransactionID`)))
                JOIN `hr`.`employee` ON ((`hr`.`employee`.`EmployeeNumber` = `sales`.`transaction`.`EmployeeNumber`)))
                JOIN `product`.`product` ON ((`product`.`product`.`SKU` = `sales`.`transactiondetail`.`SKU`)))
                JOIN `product`.`unit` ON ((`product`.`product`.`UnitID` = `product`.`unit`.`UnitID`)))
                JOIN `store`.`store` ON ((`store`.`store`.`StoreNumber` = `sales`.`transaction`.`StoreNumber`)))
                JOIN `product`.`manufacturer` ON ((`product`.`product`.`ManufacturerID` = `product`.`manufacturer`.`ManufacturerID`))) ;   

            CREATE TABLE `reconciled`.`icecream` (
              `icecreamid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
              `flavor` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
              `container` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
              `sku` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (`icecreamid`),
              UNIQUE KEY `Unique` (`flavor`,`container`)
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
    END;
    BEGIN
        CREATE VIEW `reconciled`.`totalSalesByStoreAndTemperature` AS
        SELECT StoreNumber, temperature, SUM(TotalPrice) as `SumOfTotalPrice`
        FROM reconciled.sale inner join reconciled.weather on Substring(reconciled.sale.zipCode,1,5) = substring(reconciled.weather.zipCode,1,5)
        Group By StoreNumber, temperature
        ORDER BY StoreNumber, Temperature;
    END;

END
```

Comment: with my experience in `AWS RDS`, you don't get SUPER privileges as those are used by the provisioner engine. I am pretty sure that is how it is done in `GCP`. It could be that something in query make MySQL think it needs, SUPER privileges. Posting your query which is giving the error will be helpful.

Comment: I'll post the query but it's a wall of SQL and someone will get upset.

Comment: aah. this is the problem. `DEFINER`

Comment: try `CREATE PROCEDURE CreateFullCoverageTestCase()`

Comment: The SP creates, no problem., I get the error when I run the SP

Comment: You may have to explicitly grant `root` user privileges to your SP

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add the root cause of this issue.

Cloud SQL currently is limited to grant SUPER and FILE privileges according to [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/users#root-user), so they can't be assigned to any user including root.

As per [MySQL 5.7 documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super), the DEFINER attribute requires the user to have the SUPER privilege.

The situation above was the cause of your error and it worked when you took out the DEFINER statement.

In summary any other action that requires SUPER o FILE privileges most probably will fail with the error "Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation".

Answer (score 0):

I took out the DEFINER clause in the creation of the view `reconciled`.`mapping`. 
That eliminated the error when I executed the SP.

It wasn't the DEFINER clause of the SP creation script, it was the DEFINER clause in the SP itself.

Answer (score 0):

with my experience in `AWS RDS`, you don't get `SUPER` privileges as those are used by the provisioner engine. I am pretty sure that is how it is done in `GCP`. It could be that something in query make `MySQL` think it needs `SUPER` privileges. Posting your query which is giving the error will be helpful.

-------Update after OP posted the query----------

this is the problem. `DEFINER`. try `CREATE PROCEDURE CreateFullCoverageTestCase()`